# Apache 2.4.x + PHP 7 on Windows Server 2012 R2 do not release the memory

Tags: php, windows, apache, memory-leaks

I'm using Apache 2.4.20 with PHP 7.0.6 on Windows Server 2012 R2 (all components architecture is x64). During operation of web server in the Task Manager I see that the memory used is not released, but simply accumulates. It is necessary to restart the service each time the value is 400+ MB. Sometimes it reached and 1+ GB. On Red Hat Linux is no such problem in general, and I reboot the server only when updating SSL certificate.

That is the task manager 30 minutes after the restart the Apache service:

[image: task manager 1]

And this is after few hours worked:

[image]

Help me please to resolve this problem.

Thanks in advance.